# Can I rewrite the condition that $\mu$ is a probability measure using a pushforward measure onto a singleton space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a positive Radon measure $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(X)$ (and say $X = \mathbb{R}^n$). Now pick some point $\bar x \in X$, define a singleton space $\bar X := \{\bar x\}$ and introduce a map $f\,\colon\, X \to \bar X$ given by $f(x) = \bar x$ for all $x$.

Since $\bar X$ is a singleton space, the set of positive Radon measures on $\bar X$, denoted by $\mathcal M(\bar X)$, can be identified with $\mathbb R_+$, in the sense that we simply assign some mass to $\bar x$, the only element of $\bar X$. In particular, consider $\lambda_1 \in \mathcal M(\bar X)$ which can be identified $\lambda_1 \equiv 1$ (it assigns mass 1 to $\bar x$.

Finally, let $f_{\#}\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\bar X)$ denote the pushforward measure of $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(X)$ by $f$.

Is it then true that

$$
\mu\text{ is a probability measure}\iff f_{\#} \mu = \lambda_1 ?
$$

It would seem so, because we can write
$$
\phi(\bar x) \times 1 = \int_{\bar X}\phi(\bar x) d\lambda_1 = \int_{\bar X} \phi(\bar x)df_{\#}\mu = \int_X \phi(f(x))d\mu = \phi(\bar x) \int_X d\mu 
$$
and so, since $\phi$ was arbitrary, $\int_X d\mu = 1$.

My background in measure theory is very lacking, so I would be most grateful if someone could confirm that this is fine or point out some measure theory problem with it. It does seem that the map $f$ is trivially measurable and the rest is just using definitions, so hopefully this is fine? :)

Comment: You began with "Consider a probability measure $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$" and then asked "Is it then true that $
\mu \in \mathcal{P}(X) \iff f_{\#} \mu = \lambda_1 ?$" This equivalence is "then" of course true since both sides hold, but this is not what you meant. I think you should have begun with "Consider a positive Radon measure $\mu \in \mathcal M(X)$".

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for pointing this, let me edit the question :)

Comment: Your conjecture is true, since $f_{\#} \mu = \lambda_{\mu(X)}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval to be precise, the OP have not defined $\lambda_i$ for $i\neq 1$. We can as well say that $f_*\mu = \mu(X)\cdot \lambda_1$

Comment: Indeed the OP did not define $\lambda_i,$ but their definition of $\lambda_1$ is sufficiently clear and natural to be generalized without ambiguity, as I implicitely did.